# PhpUnit and Travis

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

I need help my builds on Travis is always wrong.

The error is:

> $phpunit
>
> > The configuration file does not exist.

The travis yml:

```
"language: php
php:
  - 5.4
  -  5.6
  - 7.0
  - 7.1.9
  - 7.1.10

services:
- mysql

before_script:
 - cd Industria

script: phpunit

notifications:
  email: false"
```

My phpunit.xml is a folder in the Industria.

In bash tests always works.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if you have a **phpunit.xml.dist** in your application folder when you are running Travis?

Comment: Try `phpunit  --verbose --debug` for further information. The error message so far tells that there is no configuration file, if you wonder what that is, the Phpunit documentation describes it better I could put in a comment here: https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html / http://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/configuration.html

Comment: @FranckGamess my phpunit.xml is in a folder before, not int application

Comment: @hakre When i try the debug, i have this error:

"ERROR: Not Found        
  The controller/method pair you requested was not found."

Comment: sounds like you didn't enter it as long switche(s), prefix it w/ `--` otherwise phpunit will interprete it as argument and is looking for that test to execute. If you manage to use these switches (and maybe only one of them) successfully will make Phpunit show you the path of the configuration file that is in use.

Comment: if you don't want for a try do not execute any tests, use `--version` it will only output the version but also show the path to the configuration file w/ `--debug` a/o `--verbose`  (don't remember it all precisely from top of my head).